# Count child nodes and show on parent node in Android Expandable ListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I am using web services to populate my expandable listview having parent and child. Now i want to show the child count on parent node.

you can see it in image.
As in image Android(parent) has count 712(child Nodes), Architecture(parent) has count 115(child Nodes) and so on.

Can you please suggest me how should i do it, or link to any tutorial to do this kind of thing.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p15vG.jpg)